# RC4 not disabling

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I'm running Apache 2.2.27 - CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 kvm and cannot disable RC4 on my VPS. SSL Labs is capping my grade at "C" because of this.

Any ideas? I'm using...

```
SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 !EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS !RC4"
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
```

Comment: You might be using that statement in a wrong place and therefore it is not applied. Without seeing more details of the configuration it is hard to tell.

Comment: While not a direct answer, I would recommend https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS and its linked config generator.  Also, is space an accepted separator in addition to colon?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Thanks! You were right about the separator- I've also tried the Mozilla config generator but unfortunately that didn't work either. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation

> SSLCipherSuite ...
>
> ...
>
> This complex directive uses a **colon-separated** cipher-spec string consisting of OpenSSL ... (emphasis mine)

You should try putting a `:` in place of the  in the list.

> ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

Comment: I have no idea what an include editor is. The line SSLCipherSuite line I used as an example gets the site it came from an A+ on the Quayle SSL Labs tests btw.

Comment: Thanks @Iain - Should I include "SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3" still?

Comment: Hmmm, still doesn't seem to work. Thank you so much anyway.

Comment: Yes, and you are restarting httpd after making the changes aren't you ? Are there any relevant messages in the logs ?

Comment: Yes have been restarting. Unfortunately I don't know enough about it to find logs. I'm a web developer and I think I've bitten off more than I can chew getting a VPS. :S

Comment: Yes, it seems you have. Developer and Sysadmin skillsets are very different.

Comment: Sure are. Might need to find someone on oDesk or something. Thanks again Iain. Have a great day.

Comment: @verrucktfuchs I know how to solve this as I recently did it. If you still want it dome please contact me - see my profile for details.